# Set images visibility to be false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, invisible

I have many images that are all part of one class, here is the code:

```
class='button_cell'
```

Can I please have some help to set all of these images to not be visible via Javascript?

I use the following code to set all items in a DIV to be disabled:

```
$('#incident_div').find('input, textarea, button, select').attr('disabled',true);
```

I am guessing that the code should be similar, yet I am stuck.

May I please have some help with this?

Comment: Your title says to set the image visibility to false (meaning not visible) but your question says to set all of the images to not be invisible (which would be visible). Which one is it?

Comment: Sorry, a typo. All fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all of the images in the `button_cell` class using `$('.button_cell')` and then use the `hide()` function to hide them all, like so:

```
$('.button_cell').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, if you want to hide them use:

```
$('#incident_div').find('input, textarea, button, select').hide();
```

If you want to hide elements with class `'button_cell'` you can use

```
 ('button_cell').hide()
```

If you just want to disable them as in grey them out try:

```
$('#incident_div').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("disabled",true);
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XfVvf/

Comment: The code provided by OP is irrelevant to images or visibility, this is to "set all items in a DIV to be disabled".

Comment: I've answered both cases, I was not sure since title conflicted with what he said in the message

Comment: In fact, it's not even about this `id` or these elements or the diabled attribute, it's about images with a certain class and setting display value in CSS via show/hide() in jQuery. Irrelevant as I said above.

Answer (score 0):

To hide by class:

```
$('.button_cell').hide();
```

This will select all elements of class "button_cell" and hide them.

Similarly, to show them:

```
$('.button_cell').show();
```

Reading: [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good start, but without seeing more it is hard to know...

```
$('.button_cell').show();
```

I did show instead of hide because you said you want them to not be invisible...which means visible.

If in fact you would like them to be invisible use:

```
$('.button_cell').hide();
```